# Extracting WHERE clause to speed up query

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query shown in "Section 1" below takes over 2.5 hrs to complete. I have been tasked with speeding it up and I have a question about whether a change that I made is legitimate (i.e. will not change the result). My modified code completes in < 30 mins. Many thanks.

1) ORIGINAL QUERY

```
SELECT i.FundCD
    ,i.MaxDate
    ,v1.InfoCodeName AS ParentInfoCodeName
    ,v2.InfoCodeName
    ,FieldValue
    ,i.NotFormattedDecimalValue AS FieldValue
    ,i.AsOfDate
INTO #tmp_hfri
FROM pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy v1
INNER JOIN pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy v2 ON v1.CodeNode = v2.ParentCodeNode
INNER JOIN pmw.dbo.vFundInfo i ON v2.InfoCodeID = i.CodeID
WHERE v1.InfoCodeID IN (
        692857
        ,693600
        )
```

2)  I saw that the WHERE clause in the last line requires one of two values be present in v1.InfoCodeID. v1 So I figured that I could do a prior select of rows in v1 with those values of v1.InfoCodeID and use that in the query rather than all the rows in v1 (1049 rows) in order to speed up the full query.

3)  I did:

```
SELECT *
   INTO #t1
   FROM pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy v1 
   WHERE v1.InfoCodeID in (692857,693600)
```

4) Then ran this query. It takes < 30mins.

```
SELECT i.FundCD
    ,i.MaxDate
    ,v1.InfoCodeName AS ParentInfoCodeName
    --convert(float,replace(i.FieldValue,'%',''))*0.01 as FieldValue,
    ,v2.InfoCodeName
    ,i.NotFormattedDecimalValue AS FieldValue
    ,i.AsOfDate
INTO #tmp_hfri
FROM #t1 v1
INNER JOIN #t1 v2 ON v1.CodeNode = v2.ParentCodeNode
INNER JOIN pmw.dbo.vFundInfo i ON v2.InfoCodeID = i.CodeID
WHERE v1.InfoCodeID IN (
        692857
        ,693600
        )
```

Comment: Have you tried working with indices instead?

Comment: Do you know that there is a DBA forum on stack exchange ? You might get more/better answers there.

Comment: DBA site would be more appropriate for this question, but still, can you provide the execution plan (as provided by SMSS)? Also, table definitions for everything you use (as output by sp_help/Alt-F1 command in SSMS) would be useful.

Comment: I have seen similar performance improvements using a temp table like you did, but the real issue here I think is indexing as Matthias suggests. In particular, look at the fields pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy.InfoCodeID,  pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy.CodeNode, pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy.ParentCodeNode, and pmw.dbo.vFundInfo.CodeID

Comment: did you check if the result is the same? because i kind of doubt it. the original query says, all v1 must have v1.InfoCodeID in (692857,693600). it says nothing about v2.InfoCodeID

Comment: Did you check the Execution Plan?

Comment: I know other techniques can improve execution time. In this question I am interested in whether the temp table technique changes results.

Comment: A ツ: v1 and v2 alias the same table.

Comment: and i told you it changes results.

Comment: Do you have to use the views? Maybe the queries in the views aren't optimal themselves.

Comment: Alexei: I was not aware of the DBA site but will use it in future. i thought tags were sufficient to segregate questions. Thks.

Comment: Matthais: Indices will be worked with. This question was more an example of the more generic question of using temporary tables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a legitimate technique, but in this case you are potentially excluding rows. In the first query you are only limiting the results of `v1` with `WHERE v1.InfoCodeID IN (692857,693600)`, but in the second query because you are referencing the temporary table in place of `v2`, you are also limiting the results here, your second query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT  i.FundCD,
        i.MaxDate,
        v1.InfoCodeName AS ParentInfoCodeName,
        --convert(float,replace(i.FieldValue,'%',''))*0.01 as FieldValue,
        v2.InfoCodeName,
        i.NotFormattedDecimalValue AS FieldValue,
        i.AsOfDate
INTO    #tmp_hfri
FROM    pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy v1
        INNER JOIN pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy v2 
            ON v1.CodeNode = v2.ParentCodeNode
        INNER JOIN pmw.dbo.vFundInfo i 
            ON v2.InfoCodeID = i.CodeID
WHERE   v1.InfoCodeID IN (692857 ,693600)
AND     v2.InfoCodeID IN (692857 ,693600); -- ADDITIONAL FILTER
```

The reason you are seeing the performance difference is down to intermediate materialisation. It is a legitimate technique to force intermediate materialisation by executing smaller parts and storing the result in a temp table though. Adam Machanic has [written a pretty good article on it](http://dataeducation.com/cursors-run-just-fine/), and there is
also a [connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables) open for sql server to add a query hint to allow users to force the intermediate materialisation of a result set to avoid the need for a temp table.

You may still find that using the temp table is faster, but you would still need to refer to the view for `v2`:

```
SELECT CodeNode, InfoCodeName -- ONLY PUT FIELDS YOU NEED INTO THE TEMP TABLE
INTO #t1
FROM pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy v1 
WHERE v1.InfoCodeID in (692857,693600)

SELECT  i.FundCD,
        i.MaxDate,
        v1.InfoCodeName AS ParentInfoCodeName,
        --convert(float,replace(i.FieldValue,'%',''))*0.01 as FieldValue,
        v2.InfoCodeName,
        i.NotFormattedDecimalValue AS FieldValue,
        i.AsOfDate
INTO    #tmp_hfri
FROM    #t1 v1
        INNER JOIN pmw.dbo.vInfoCodeWithHierarchy v2 
            ON v1.CodeNode = v2.ParentCodeNode
        INNER JOIN pmw.dbo.vFundInfo i 
            ON v2.InfoCodeID = i.CodeID;
```

If you are still encountering performance issues (which even with the query reduced to 30 minutes I would guess you are), then you need to look at the execution plan, identify the bottlenecks and possibly create some indexes.